Generalized Wachspress barycentric coordinates definition seems broken?
I am trying to learn about generalized barycentric coordinates. This document, defines them (on page 8) as follows:
$$ \frac{A(v_{i-1}, v_{i}, v_{i+1})}{ A(x, v_{i-1}, v_i) A(x, v_i, v_{i+1})} $$
Where $A$ is the signed area of the triangle formed by the input vertices, $x$ is the current point and $v_i$ are the vertices of the polygon.
This definition doesn't make sense to me, if $x$ lies exactly on $v_i$ then this ratio goes to infinity. Thus the vertices in the polygon cannot be evaluated.

I'm just now learning about this too.  It looks to me like this formulation as a ratio is just an optimization, and yeah it looks unstable when at or near the boundary of the polygon. Instead, I'd try expressing it as $A(v_{i-1},v_i,v_{i+1})$ times the product of the areas of all the triangles except those two, as shown in the picture in http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/MHBD02.pdf . This will be inefficient for computing all n barycentric coordinates when n is large, but I think you can avoid that with a smarter optimization that is stable. I'll write this up as an answer if it pans out.

There is a paper called Charrot Gregory Patches which seems to have  a much more reasonable set of barycentric coordinates.

According to this paper,
the formula for (non-normalized) Wachspress coordinate of point p corresponding to vertex $v_{i}$ is:
$$
    w_{i} = A(v_{i-1},v_{i},v_{i+1}) A(v_{i+1},v_{i+2},p) ... A(v_{i-2}, v_{i-1}, p)
$$
I.e. it's the product of the area of the i'th "boundary" triangle formed by the polygon's three adjacent vertices,
and the areas of the n-2 interior triangles formed by the point p and each of the polygon's edges that do not
include $v_{i}$.
Then to normalize the n coordinates, we divide them all by their sum, so the final sum is 1.
That's stable (no zero-divided-by-zero) as long as the polygon is non-degenerate (i.e. no three vertices collinear),
but it's not an efficient formula if n is large.  It's also probably prone to overflow and underflow if n is large.
It looks to me like the formula you give, from the paper you cited,
is intended to be an optimization, formed by taking the above formula and dividing through by the (constant, over all $v_{i}$) product of all n interior triangles formed with p.
The resulting formula is more efficient to calculate when n is large, and it's equivalent to the above,
as long as none of the denominators are zero or near-zero, i.e. as long as p isn't on or near the boundary of the polygon.
If p is on or near the boundary, then the formula blows up.
It seems strange that both the paper you refer to, and the one I refer to above, both give formulas that blow up at and near the boundary.
It seems to me that this can be fixed pretty easily:
instead of dividing the original formula by the product of the areas of all the n triangles formed with p,
divide by all but the smallest two of those areas (in absolute value).
So the fixed formula can be expressed as:
$$
w_{i} = \frac{A(v_{i-1}, v_{i}, v_{i+1}) A(v_{i_{0}},v_{i_{0}+1},p) A(v_{i_{1}},v_{i_{1}+1},p)}{ A(v_{i-1}, v_{i}, p) A(v_{i}, v_{i+1}, p)}
$$
where $A(v_{i_{0}},v_{i_{0}+1},p) A(v_{i_{1}},v_{i_{1}+1},p)$ are the smallest-in-absolute-value two of the n areas.
When a specific triangle area appears in both the numerator and denominator, we simply
cancel it from both before performing the division; this avoids zero-divided-by-zero, as long as at most two of the triangle areas with p are zero
(which holds as long as the polygon is non-degenerate).
The following pictures show Wachspress-coordinate interpolation of vertex colors on a regular and irregular hexagon
(similar to pictures at the beginning of the paper I referred to above).
First, using the formula you cited: the white pixels are where zero-divide was encountered,
thus confirming your observation that the formula blows up on the boundary:


And here are the same pictures generated with the fixed formula: we can observe that the zero-divide
problem has gone away.


Here is the python program that generated the above 4 pictures.
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Writes 4 image files in the current directory:
#     wachspress_answer.smart=False.irregular=False.ppm
#     wachspress_answer.smart=False.irregular=True.ppm
#     wachspress_answer.smart=True.irregular=False.ppm
#     wachspress_answer.smart=True.irregular=True.ppm

import math
import sys

# Some vector utilities

# vector divided by scalar
def vds(v,s): return tuple(x/s for x in v)
# (row) matrix times vector
def vxm(v,m): return tuple(sum(x*row[icol] for x,row in zip(v,m)) for icol in range(len(m[0])))
# vector euclidean distance
def dist(a,b): return math.sqrt(sum((y-x)**2 for x,y in zip(a,b)))

def TwiceSignedTriArea(a, b, c):
  return (b[0]-a[0])*(c[1]-a[1]) - (b[1]-a[1])*(c[0]-a[0])

# Returns the indices of the smallest and second-smallest items in the iterable.
# Iterates through the iterable exactly once.
# If it's short (less than 2 items), None will be returned for one or both indices.
def ArgMin2(iterable):
  i0,x0,i1,x1 = None,None,None,None
  for i,x in enumerate(iterable):
    if i1 is None or x < x1:
      if i0 is None or x < x0:
        i1,x1 = i0,x0
        i0,x0 = i,x
      else:
        i1,x1 = i,x
  return (i0,i1)

def WachspressBarycentrics(p, verts, smart:bool):  # {
  n = len(verts)

  edge_tri_signed_areas = [TwiceSignedTriArea(p, verts[i], verts[(i+1)%n])
                           for i in range(n)]
  vert_tri_signed_areas = [TwiceSignedTriArea(verts[(i-1)%n], verts[i], verts[(i+1)%n])
                           for i in range(n)]

  if smart:
    indices_of_the_two_closest_ish_edges = ArgMin2(abs(signed_area)
                                                   for signed_area in edge_tri_signed_areas)
    iedges_to_multiply_by = indices_of_the_two_closest_ish_edges
  else:
    iedges_to_multiply_by = ()

  coeffs = []
  for ivert in range(n):
    iedges_to_divide_by = ((ivert-1)%n, ivert)  # the two edges incident on ivert
    # If there are any factors common to the numerator and denominor,
    # we cancel them out of both.  This avoids zero-divided-by-zero
    # in the case that p is close to one or two (but not more) polygon edges.
    coeff = vert_tri_signed_areas[ivert]
    coeff *= math.prod(edge_tri_signed_areas[iedge]
                       for iedge in iedges_to_multiply_by
                       if iedge not in iedges_to_divide_by)
    coeff /= math.prod(edge_tri_signed_areas[iedge]
                       for iedge in iedges_to_divide_by
                       if iedge not in iedges_to_multiply_by)
    coeffs.append(coeff)

  coeffs = vds(coeffs, sum(coeffs))

  # Sanity check answer: coeffs should sum to 1.
  assert abs(sum(coeffs) - 1.) < 1e-6

  # Sanity check answer: coeffs times the vertices should equal the point.
  # (Note: this fails pretty quickly when not very far outside the irregular polygon)
  should_be_p = vxm(coeffs, verts)
  p_error = dist(should_be_p, p)
  assert p_error <= 1e-12, (should_be_p, p, p_error)

  return coeffs
# } WachspressBarycentrics


def main(argv):

  def SmokeTest():

    verts = ((0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1))

    for smart in [False, True]:
      barys = WachspressBarycentrics((.5,.5), verts, smart=smart)
      assert barys == (.25, .25, .25, .25)
      barys = WachspressBarycentrics((.25,.25), verts, smart=smart)
      assert barys == (9/16, 3/16, 1/16, 3/16)

    barys = WachspressBarycentrics((0,0), verts, smart=True)
    assert barys == (1, 0, 0, 0)
    barys = WachspressBarycentrics((1,0), verts, smart=True)
    assert barys == (0, 1, 0, 0)
    barys = WachspressBarycentrics((1,1), verts, smart=True)
    assert barys == (0, 0, 1, 0)
    barys = WachspressBarycentrics((0,1), verts, smart=True)
    assert barys == (0, 0, 0, 1)

    barys = WachspressBarycentrics((.5,0), verts, smart=True)
    assert barys == (.5,.5,0,0)


  # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example
  def image_to_ppm_string(image):
    h = len(image)
    w = 0 if h==0 else len(image[0])
    answer = 'P3\n'
    answer += f"{w} {h}\n"
    answer += f"255\n"
    for row in image:
      for pixel in row:
        for x in pixel:
          answer += f" {round(relerp(clamp(x,0,1),0,1,0,255))}"
    return answer

  # Some more math utilities...

  # "re-linearly interpolate" x from x0..x1 to y0..y1
  def relerp(x, x0,x1, y0,y1): return y0 + (y1-y0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0) if x-x0<=x1-x else y1 - (y1-y0)*(x1-x)/(x1-x0)
  # clamp x to interval [a,b]
  def clamp(x,a,b): return a if x<=a else b if x>=b else x

  def MakeTheFourImages():  # {
    # like the picture in the paper
    # "Generalized Barycentric Coordinates on Irregular Polygons"
    # http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/MHBD02.pdf
    vertex_colors = [
      [1,0,0],  # r
      [1,1,0],  # y
      [0,0,1],  # b
      [1,0,1],  # m
      [0,1,0],  # g
      [0,1,1],  # c
    ]

    # but this seems a lot nicer (just the color wheel)
    vertex_colors = [
      [1,0,0],  # r
      [1,1,0],  # y
      [0,1,0],  # g
      [0,1,1],  # c
      [0,0,1],  # b
      [1,0,1],  # m
    ]

    n = len(vertex_colors)

    mag = 16  # size of big pixels
    imgsize = 43  # number of big pixels.  odd so center will be in the middle of a pixel
    center = imgsize/2  # yes, on a half-big-pixel

    frame_color = (0,0,0)  # black
    nan_color = (1,1,1)  # white

    hexagon_almost_regular = [(center+2*x,center-2*y) for x,y in [(9,0),(5,8),(-5,8),(-9,0),(-5,-8),(5,-8)]]
    hexagon_highly_irregular = [(center+5*x,center-5*y) for x,y in [(4,0),(0,2),(-2,1),(-3,0),(-4,-2),(-2,-3)]]

    def DistanceFromPolygon(p, verts):
      n = len(verts)
      answer = -math.inf
      for i in range(n):
        # left-handed coord system, argh, so negate
        answer = max(answer, -TwiceSignedTriArea(p,verts[i],verts[i-1]) / dist(verts[i],verts[i-1]))
      return answer

    for smart in [False, True]:  # {
      for irregular in [False, True]:  # {

        verts = (hexagon_highly_irregular if irregular else hexagon_almost_regular)

        image = []
        for irow in range(imgsize):
          image.append([])
          for icol in range(imgsize):
            x = icol+.5
            y = irow+.5
            if DistanceFromPolygon((x,y), verts) > 1e-3:
              color = (.5,.5,.5)  # 50% gray
            else:
              try:
                barys = WachspressBarycentrics(p=(x,y), verts=verts, smart=smart)
              except ZeroDivisionError:
                color = nan_color
              else:
                color = vxm(barys, vertex_colors)

            image[-1].append(color)

        def magnify_image(image, mag):
          answer = []
          for row in image:
            for i in range(mag):
              answer.append([])
              for pixel in row:
                for j in range(mag):
                  answer[-1].append(pixel)
          return answer

        def rect(image, icol0,icol1, irow0,irow1, color):
          nrows = len(image)
          ncols = 0 if nrows==0 else len(image[0])
          for irow in range(irow0,irow1):
            for icol in range(icol0,icol1):
              if irow >= 0 and irow < nrows and icol >= 0 and icol < ncols:
                image[irow][icol] = color

        def magnify_image_and_frame_these_pixels(image, mag, frame_these_pixels,
                                                 inner_frame_thickness, outer_frame_thickness,
                                                 frame_color):
          answer = magnify_image(image, mag)
          for Icol,Irow in frame_these_pixels:
            irow0 = Irow*mag
            irow1 = (Irow+1)*mag
            icol0 = Icol*mag
            icol1 = (Icol+1)*mag
            rect(answer, icol0-outer_frame_thickness,icol1+outer_frame_thickness,
                         irow0-outer_frame_thickness,irow0+inner_frame_thickness, frame_color)
            rect(answer, icol0-outer_frame_thickness,icol1+outer_frame_thickness,
                         irow1-inner_frame_thickness,irow1+outer_frame_thickness, frame_color)
            rect(answer, icol0-outer_frame_thickness,icol0+inner_frame_thickness,
                         irow0+inner_frame_thickness,irow1-inner_frame_thickness, frame_color)
            rect(answer, icol1-inner_frame_thickness,icol1+outer_frame_thickness,
                         irow0+inner_frame_thickness,irow1-inner_frame_thickness, frame_color)
          return answer


        image = magnify_image_and_frame_these_pixels(image, mag, frame_these_pixels=[[round(x-.5) for x in xy] for xy in verts],
            inner_frame_thickness=0,
            outer_frame_thickness=4,
            frame_color=frame_color)

        ppm_string = image_to_ppm_string(image)

        filename = f"wachspress_answer.smart={smart}.irregular={irregular}.ppm"
        print(f"Writing {filename!r}... ", end='', file=sys.stderr)
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
          print(ppm_string, file=file)
        print(f"done.", file=sys.stderr)
      # }  for irregular in [False, True]
    # }  for smart in [False, True]
  # }  MakeTheFourImages

  SmokeTest()
  MakeTheFourImages()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)


